# Android: How to make a percentage of a bitmap black and white, retaining color in the rest?

Tags: java, android, graphics, colors, bitmap

I've got a bitmap displayed in an `ImageView`, and I want to be able to make a certain percentage of the image black and white, and have the other part retain it's color. For example, if 60% is the target percentage, the image would look like this: [image: would look like this]. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've got a bitmap displayed in an `ImageView`, and I want to be able to
>   make a certain percentage of the image black and white, and have the
>   other part retain it's color. For example, if 60% is the target
>   percentage.

It seems (from your image) you mean `monochrome` (i.e. `greyscale`), not black and white.

Something like this should do it (tested **o.k.**):

```
void doIt(ImageView image)
{
    //get bitmap from your ImageView (image)
    Bitmap originalBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    int height = originalBitmap.getHeight();
    int fortyPercentHeight = (int) Math.floor(height * 40.0 / 100.0);

    //create a bitmap of the top 40% of image height that we will make black and white
    Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, originalBitmap.getWidth() , fortyPercentHeight );
    //make it monochrome
    Bitmap blackAndWhiteBitmap = monoChrome(croppedBitmap);
    //copy the monochrome bmp (blackAndWhiteBitmap) to the original bmp (originalBitmap)
    originalBitmap = overlay(originalBitmap, blackAndWhiteBitmap);
    //set imageview to new bitmap
    image.setImageBitmap(originalBitmap );
}

Bitmap monoChrome(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    Bitmap bmpMonochrome = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpMonochrome);
    ColorMatrix ma = new ColorMatrix();
    ma.setSaturation(0);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(ma));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    return bmpMonochrome;
}

Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) 
{
    Bitmap bmp3 = bmp1.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);//mutable copy
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp3 );
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
    return bmp3 ;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I have never used a canvas before so I'm happy to have this opportunity to learn about them. Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome @KOG. As a new user this site can be a bit intimidating.  (we have quite strict quality control, unlike other sites) Please take a moment to see the [site your](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). (you get a badge for looking at it!) Enjoy StackOverflow. Be prepared for brutal analysis of your questions ! It's a mostly user monitored site so where people are involved, random things happen, if you have a complaint, refer it to the moderators (flag). Remeber to vote (a lot) on things you like or dislike, it's important for quality control. Happy hunting.

Comment: How could I reverse this? So, start with the black and white image, and have the colored version of the image fill up the first 40%? I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: Hmmm it seems you have *not understood the code*, what you want is very simple, the `croppedBitmap needs to be the bottom 60%. It's all about the co-ordinates.I will start you off `Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, 0,  fortyPercentHeight, originalBitmap.getWidth() , originalBitmap.getHeight());`

Comment: I want the original bitmap to now be the black and white one. I modified your code a bit, so I made a separate post. Please check out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124575/android-cropping-an-image-from-the-bottom-up