# Android: Cropping an Image from the Bottom Up

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have an image, and I am trying to overlay a cropped version of the image over the original. Something like this:

Original
[image: Original Image]

Overlay Image
[image]

Image after the overlay image is cropped to roughly 50%
[image]

Right now, my code below reverses what I want, and returns an image like this:

[image]

```
public void setOverlay(ImageView image, Bitmap originalBitmap, double percentageCompleted) {
        int percentHeight;
        int height = originalBitmap.getHeight();
        Bitmap cropped;
        if(percentageCompleted == 0){
            cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, overlay.getWidth() , 0 );
        } else {
            percentHeight = (int) Math.floor(height *  (percentageCompleted));
            Log.d("HEIGHT", Double.toString(height));
            Log.d("PERCENT Completed", Double.toString(percentageCompleted));
            Log.d("PERCENT HEIGHT", Integer.toString(percentHeight));
            cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(overlay, 0, 0, overlay.getWidth() , height-percentHeight);
        }

        originalBitmap = overlay(originalBitmap, cropped);

        //set imageview to new bitmap
        image.setImageBitmap(originalBitmap );
    }

    public Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
        Bitmap bmp3 = bmp1.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);//mutable copy
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp3 );
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
        return bmp3;
    }
```

I know I could reverse the image files, but I want to start with the original image and have the overlay draw upwards, rather than starting with the overlay, and drawing the original downwards. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)
```

Here is my `overlay` method that may meet your need:

```
public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap base, Bitmap overlay, Float percentage) {
    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(base.getWidth(), base.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    // base bitmap
    canvas.drawBitmap(base, 0F, 0F, paint);

    // overlay bitmap
    int yOffset = (int) (percentage * base.getHeight());
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, yOffset, overlay.getWidth(), overlay.getHeight());
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, rect, rect, paint);
    return resultBitmap;
}
```