# Android: Blur image from only left side

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I want to apply a blur effect on the background image in my app. I tried a lot of solutions and tricks available on the net, but they are only blurring out the whole image, but  my requirement is to blur the from only left and bottom, is there any technique for doing this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

    LinearLayout blurimage = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bg);
    Bitmap blurimages = BlurImage(((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_background)).getBitmap());
    blurimage.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(blurimages));
}

@SuppressLint({"NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi"})
public Bitmap BlurImage(Bitmap input) {
    RenderScript rsScript = RenderScript.create(SampleActivity.this);
    Allocation alloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, input);
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rsScript, Element.U8_4(rsScript));
    blur.setRadius(10);
    blur.setInput(alloc);

    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight(), input.getConfig());
    Allocation outAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rsScript, result);
    blur.forEach(outAlloc);
    outAlloc.copyTo(result);

    rsScript.destroy();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: An image example might help show what you mean. It's quite easy to do. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639136/android-how-to-make-a-percentage-of-a-bitmap-black-and-white-retaining-color-i/49640696#49640696) to see the principle/technique.

Comment: I want to make it blur from the edges. Only left and bottom and this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to blur some part of Image then you need to cut that part before feeding it to your blur algorithm.

You can obtain `Canvas` from `bitmap` like this. The `bitmap` must be `mutable`.

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap name);
```

To cut a part of `bitmap` we need a `Rect` to specify the subset in which we are interested, let's name it `srcRect`. We need another `Rect` in which our original bitmap will be scaled to fit into, let's name that `destRect`.

Declare your blur bitmap dimens

```
 int blurBitmapWidth = 50;
 int blurBitmapHeight = 50;
```

Declare your Rectangles

```
 Bitmap original = decode form resources....
 Rect srcRect = new Rect(0, original.getHeight() - blurBitmapHeight, blurBitmapWidth, original.getHeight());  // bottom left portion
 Rect destRect = new Rect(0, 0, blurBitmapWidth, blurBitmapHeight);
 Bitmap croppedBitmap = cutBitmap(original, srcRect, destRect);
```

CutBitmap method

```
private Bitmap cutBitmap(final Bitmap originalBmp, Rect src, Rect dest) {
    Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dest.width(), dest.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(croppedBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(originalBmp, src, dest, null);
    return croppedBitmap;
}
```

Now `croppedBitmap` contains bottom left portion of your `original`.Feed it into your blur algorithm.

Further if you want to draw blurred part onto `original`, then you simply obtain a `canvas` on `original bitmap` and draw `blurred bitmap` using `srcRect`.

```
Canvas c = new Canvas(original);
c.drawBitmap(bitmap obtained from blur algorithm, srcRect.left, srcRect.top, null);
```

Comment: Thank you for your ans. you are passing two parameters to cutBitmap, what is croppedBmp here? could you please show it.

Comment: `@param originalBmp` is the one whose part you want to blur, `@param croppedBmp` is the one which will contain chosen part of original one. You can create `croppedBmp` inside this `method` also, I have kept it out of method so as not to create a fresh `Bitmap` if you need to adjust parts to crop at runtime. After this  `method` returns `croppedBmp` will contain part of `originalBmp`.

Comment: sorry this is not working for me. how are creating croppedBmp